# Problem with embed on a collection of forms of Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

**InvalidPropertyPathException**

If I submit  the form, without completing the data. I get this error.

Could not parse property path "children[upcomingTours].children[[0]].children[address].children[street].data". Unexpected token "]" at position 36.

Some questions :

1. Is this a symfony bug? If so, is it already fixed in version
   5.x?
2. Has anyone ever encountered this error?
3. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Thank you in advance for your reply

**This is the hierarchy of my form**

```
 - TourType (custom form)
        - UcomingTour (CollectionType)
             - AddressType (custom form)
```

**HTLM**

```
<div>
<label for="tour_upcomingTours_0_address_street">Adresse</label>
<input type="text" 
       id="tour_upcomingTours_0_address_street" 
       name="tour[upcomingTours][0][address][street]" 
       placeholder="Tapez un nom de rue">
</div>
```

**TourType**

```
class TourType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ......
            ->add('upcomingTours', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'entry_type' => UpcomingTourType::class,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

**UpcomingTourType**

```
class UpcomingTourType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
             .........
             ->add('address', AddressType::class, [
                    'label' => false,
             ])
    }

}
```

**AddressType**

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ............
            ->add('street', null, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.address_line',
                'attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'admin.placeholder_line'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotNull([
                        'message' => 'project.street_not_blank',
                    ])
                ]
            ])
           
        ;
    }
}
```

**TourController**

```
class TourController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/tour/new/", name="dashboard_tour_new", methods={"GET","POST"},
     *          defaults={"_locale" = "%locale%"},
     *          requirements={"_locale" = "%app_locales%"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $tour = new Tour();
        $upcomingTour = new UpcomingTour();
        $tour->getUpcomingTours()->add($upcomingTour);
        $form = $this->createForm(TourType::class, $tour);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution.

**Problem**

The origin of the problem is the validation of the constraints on the form.
Symfony collectionType encounters a problem when trying to map the Address form

**Solution**

The solution is the following:

- I remove the valuation of the contrants in the form and put it in the entity.

I delete this code:

```
'constraints' => [
    new NotNull([
          'message' => 'project.street_not_blank',
       ])
 ]
```

**AddressType**

```
class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ............
            ->add('street', null, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'admin.address_line',
                'attr' => [ 'placeholder' => 'admin.placeholder_line'],
            ])
           
        ;
    }
}
```

Then I put it in the entity

**Entity Address**

```
class Address extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="project.street_not_blank")
     */
    private $street;
```

}

**Conclusion**

> I think it's a symfony bug, for me it will have to support the two
> method

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the following lines from the controller

```
$upcomingTour = new UpcomingTour();
$tour->getUpcomingTours()->add($upcomingTour);
```

or wrap these lines in `if ($request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_GET))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I try and the form works fine and it shows error validation. But the problem what I need these lines to display a default form ..

Comment: You can add 'upcomingTour' by JavaScript